# RSS Feeder for Android - Full Article

Tags: android, rss

I am developing android app that pulls news from RSS feeder, store them on a host and then display the news on the app.

The problem I have is that the RSS feeder only provides the title and a small part of the article such the BBC RSS feeder.

http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/news/rss.xml

I would like to know if there is a way to extract the entire article through the RSS feeder or any other means and store them on the host so that the app will display the whole article.

If more info is required please let me know

Thanks in advance

Samer

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way to do that is to get the rss feed, and after request the article page, get the html and extract the content.

Here is a link about Httprequest: 
http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/HttpRequest.html

Answer (score 0):

In the case of the BBC feed you linked, the feed is only giving you a small description of the article. This is quite common, probably because they want the user to visit their website to read the full article.

To get the full article you would need to follow the url in the  element and then [scrape](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_scraping) that website for the full text, using for example [Httprequest](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/HttpRequest.html). This will require different code for every different feed you want to get an article from because the websites look different.

Also their might be legal issues using their full article text without permission (but that is not my area of expertise).